# How to add multiple Controllers that are same instance to my tabBarController?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa

I want to add multiple Controllers that are same instance to my tabBarController.but I can't.the added controllers of array treated as a one controller. How I should do ??and What is the best way??this is my code.

```
RootViewController *rootViewController = [[[RootViewController alloc]init]autorelease];
tabBarController = [[[UITabBarController alloc]init]autorelease];
[tabBarController setDelegate:self];
[tabBarController setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:rootViewController,rootViewController,rootViewController,rootViewController,rootViewController,nil] animated:NO];
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this :

```
RootViewController *rootViewController = [[[RootViewController alloc]init]autorelease];
RootViewController *rootViewController2 = [rootViewController retain];
RootViewController *rootViewController3 = [rootViewController retain];

tabBarController = [[[UITabBarController alloc]init]autorelease];
[tabBarController setDelegate:self];
    [tabBarController setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:rootViewController, rootViewController2, rootViewController3, nil] animated:NO];
```

Comment: thank you for replying ! I want to add multiple Controllers that are same instance.

Comment: Arg, sorry I read your question too fast... I've edited my anwser.

Comment: this answer is so cool!but this code doesn't work...:( still my tabbarController has only one tab.

Comment: Do you really want to have the same instance ? What if you get different instances of the same object ?

Comment: Hi i am also facing the same issue because creating viewcontroller programmatically so need to set same instance.

Comment: yes,I want to really have the same instance.because I want to control switching view by only one controller.Reason of using UITab is that UITab supports autosizing. Certainly I can create tab from scratch,but it is tired.